# VKSdk.login(this, scope); Sdk login callback

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, android-vksdk

Я пишу приложение под Android, оно использует API Вконтакте. Прежде чем использовать его методы, я должен залогиниться с помощью метода  `VKSdk.login`. Я делаю это так:

```
VKSdk.login(this, some_scope);
// код, который должен выполняться после логина #1
```

После вызова этого метода открывается активити авторизации, где я должен залогиниться, после чего смогу работать с api. Но тут есть проблема. Сразу после открытия этой актвитити метод `login` завершается, и продолжается выполнение кода после него. Но так кака я ещё не залогинился, я получаю исключение. Насколько я понимаю, метод `login` не асинхронный и не принимает никаких коллбеков. Вопрос: как решить эту проблему? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Согласно документации результат авторизации придёт в onActivityResult. Там его можно обработать, в т.к. колбэк повесить. Именно в него вам и надо исполнять код, который идёт после успешной авторизации.